# How can I export in flash on the fly a MovieClip into a vector file (SVG, EPS)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, svg, arrays

I'm trying to build an app allowing the user to arrange different shapes, add text, and export the result as a vector file.

I've been looking into [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) libraries and especially the [SVGShapeExporter class](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/blob/master/src/com/codeazur/as3swf/exporters/SVGShapeExporter.as).

It works fine if you load an swf in the app and try to export it on the fly into an svg file but I'd like to work with movieClips instead of loaded swfs.

Since as3swf.SWF objects are based on ByteArrays, I've been trying to get a ByteArray for my MovieClip but it seems to be empty.

Any idea?

Thanks